# Why does Hibernate goes StackOverflowError when many-to-one is lazy?

Tags: java, hibernate, stack-overflow, hibernate-mapping

I have the following table schema, where a *simulation* has many *searches* and any *search* has many *properties*.

[image: table schema]

Since I would like to persist a Simulation entity with its searches and their properties **all at once**, I mapped my entity like this:

***Simulation.java***

```java
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
@ToString(exclude = "searches")
@Entity
@Table(name = "SIMULATION")
public class Simulation implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "simulation_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "simulation_generator", sequenceName = "SIMULATION_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "SIMULATION_ID")
    private Set<SimulationSearch> searches = new HashSet<>(0);

    // other fields
}
```

***SimulationSearch.java***

```java
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
@ToString(exclude = "properties")
@Entity
@Table(name = "SIM_SEARCH")
public class SimulationSearch implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private SimulationSearchId id;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "SIMULATION_ID", referencedColumnName = "SIMULATION_ID"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "POSITION", referencedColumnName = "POSITION")
    })
    private Set<SimulationSearchProperty> properties = new HashSet<>(0);

    // other fields...

    @Data
    public static class SimulationSearchId implements Serializable {
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "SIMULATION_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
        private Simulation simulation;
        private int position;
    }
}
```

***SimulationSearchProperties.java***

```java
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
@Entity
@Table(name = "SIM_SEARCH_PROPERTY")
public class SimulationSearchProperty implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private SimulationSearchPropertyId id;
    private String value;

    @Data
    public static class SimulationSearchPropertyId implements Serializable {
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumns({
                @JoinColumn(name = "SIMULATION_ID", referencedColumnName = "SIMULATION_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false),
                @JoinColumn(name = "POSITION", referencedColumnName = "POSITION", insertable = false, updatable = false)
        })
        private SimulationSearch search;
        private String label;
    }
}
```

What happens is that Hibernate keeps printing the following query untill it goes on StackOverflowError.

```sql
select simulation0_.*, searches1_.*, properties5_.*
  from simulation simulation0_ 
  left outer join sim_search searches1_ on simulation0_.id = searches1_.simulation_id
  left outer join sim_search_property properties5_ on searches1_.position = properties5_.position and searches1_.simulation_id = properties5_.simulation_id
 where simulation0_.id = ?
```

While mapping between `Simulation` and `SimulationSearch` is very similar to `SimulationSearch` and `SimulationSearchProperty` mapping, this error started happening when I set `ManyToOne` annotation of `SimulationSearch#properties` as lazy fetch and didn't stop even if I set `SimulationSearchPropertyId#search` as lazy too.

What am I missing?

**UPDATES**

I'm using Hibernate 4.2.6.Final

Partial stacktrace log:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.QueryParameters.<init>(QueryParameters.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.QueryParameters.<init>(QueryParameters.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.QueryParameters.<init>(QueryParameters.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2114)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3927)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:460)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:429)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:262)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1092)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1019)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:672)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:490)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:667)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.nullSafeGet(ComponentType.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.hydrate(ManyToOneType.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.hydrate(ComponentType.java:642)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:775)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:708)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:943)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:911)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:312)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2121)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3927)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:460)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:429)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:262)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1092)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1019)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:672)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:490)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:667)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.nullSafeGet(ComponentType.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.hydrate(ManyToOneType.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.hydrate(ComponentType.java:642)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:775)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:708)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:943)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:911)
    ...
```

I've just updated a bit the entity mapping, removing `mappedBy` annotation attribute and adding instead `@JoinColumn`s annotations.
Now persistence is working fine, but the StackOverflowError is still there when I try to load a single simulation.

I've also cleaned up Hibernate generated sql removing uninteresting pieces of information.

Comment: Please also include the stacktrace of the stackoverflow exception.

Comment: What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: I've updated my question, btw the exception has just internal calls, and I'm using Hibernate 4.2.6

Comment: It looks like your annotations are not correct... Hibernate does not recognize that you have a bidirectional relationship and treats your relations both as unidirectional. I'll try to form a proper answer later...

Comment: It doesn't seems to be an hash or toString recursion causing the stackoverflow error: I've tried removing `@Data` in favor of `@Getter` and `@Setter` in `SimulationSearchPropertyId` but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to annotate you relationship to be bidirectional.

For your first class the change should be

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
@ToString(exclude = "searches")
@Entity
@Table(name = "SIMULATION")
public class Simulation implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "simulation_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "simulation_generator", sequenceName = "SIMULATION_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "SimulationSearchId")
    private Set<SimulationSearch> searches = new HashSet<>(0);

    // other fields
}
```

Without the attribute `mappedBy` a JPA provider assumes that you have 2 unidirectional relationship, which leads to an infinite circle reference between your data.

## Reference

JSR 338: Java TM Persistence API, Version 2.1

11.1.40 OneToMany Annotation

4th paragraph, 2nd sentence

> If the relationship is bidirectional, the
> `mappedBy` element must be used to specify the relationship field or property of the entity that is the
> owner of the relationship.

Comment: I'v added the `mappedBy` attribute on both `OneToMany` annotations, but I get an Hibernate exception:
`org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Associations marked as mappedBy must not define database mappings like @JoinTable or @JoinColumn: it.netechgroup.fastcheck.simulation.model.SimulationModel.searches`

Comment: Then, if I remove the `JoinColumn` annotations, I'm back to the original question state and the StackoverflowError is still there.

Comment: The `@JoinColumn` annotations at the `@ManyToOne` should/could stay. Only at the `@OneToMany` end they are not needed.

Comment: I only removed the `@JoinColumn` on the `@OneToMany`, but apparently nothing changed.